# transpose row into column for each date in time series using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, transpose

I have a series of swaption time series data for each expiry & tenor for the last year - I am looking to transpose it into a simple grid for each day (using date as index) using pandas dataframe (that can then be used to build a dash grid)

From the below: [image]

into something like this for each day:
[image]

Given the repeated 1m, 3m, 6m etc in the top row, I am not sure how to transpose it whilst keeping the date as key index:

Comment: What is the output of `df.info()`? Did you try `df.unstack(level=1)`?

Comment: can you provide input as copyable text or code? [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: sorry for not being clear - I am uploading data from excel (picture above), it enters python in the format below:

the expiries upload with .2, .3 after them as not unique, i am looking to transpose the expiries to create a 8 x 6 grid storing the vol surface for each date (looks like above).

Comment: Date 1m 1m.1 1m.2 1m.3 1m.4 1m.5 1m.6 1m.7 1m.8 ... 6m.8 1y 1y.1 1y.2 1y.3 1y.4 1y.5 1y.6 1y.7 1y.8
0 NaT 1y 2y 3y 5y 7y 10y 15y 20y 30y ... 30y 1y 2y 3y 5y 7y 10y 15y 20y 30y
1 2024-01-07 40 42 44 46 50 52 55 57 59 ... 57 36 38 40 42 46 48 51 53 55
2 rows × 37 columns

Comment: df info() gives
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 37 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Date    1 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   1m      2 non-null      object        
 2   1m.1    2 non-null      object        
 3   1m.2    2 non-null      object        
 4   1m.3    2 non-null      object        
etc      
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(36)
memory usage: 724.0+ bytes

Comment: Are those "3"s on the second picture the expected result? Could you describe some logic of  what each cell means?

Comment: @CPbeginner: can you check my solution bellow?

Answer (score 1):

The solution has two steps: (1) convert column-wide data into long table, (2) convert long table to index-wide

Create example and save in CSV format:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Create example 
csv_data = """year,A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C
,x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z
2003,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2004,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
2005,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
2006,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38
2007,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,25
2008,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58
2009,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68
2010,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78
"""

# Save example data in CSV:
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), header=[0, 1])
df.to_csv('data_example.csv', index=False)
```

Reading file from CSV, using multilevel columns

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_example.csv', header=[0,1], skipinitialspace=False)
df
```

Fix the `multilevel` of columns

```
index_tuples = df.columns.tolist()
index_tuples[0] = ('year', '')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_tuples)
df
```

Step 01: Convert to long-format dataframe

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars='year')
df2
```

Step 02: Convert to multilevel-index dataframe

```
# Change columns name:    
df2.columns = ['year', 'headerlvl1', 'headerlvl2', 'value']

# Using pivot_table:
df2.pivot_table(values='value', index=['year', 'headerlvl2'], columns='headerlvl1')
```

Hope this is what you are looking for